# Android app crashes on release mode

Tags: android, google-play, android-sqlite, android-debug

I have tested my android app(debug-apk) on android devices it's working fine but it is crashing in release mode.

I think it is problem in configuration but i am unable to recognise it.
Please suggest.

```
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Login (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Login
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
```

Comment: @PramodYadav i have edited question please check.

Comment: it clearly say that you have no table as login in your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have recognised problem,it is build.gradle file i have commented this lines from file then its working fine

```
minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: Why does it do that when minifyEnabled is set to true.
We should be able to minify...